# Expectation function and interaction

Tags: conditional-expectation

I have a basic question. Suppose I know random variables A and B take two values, 0 and 1. And I know:

$$E[A] = 0.5$$
$$E[B] = 0.5$$

$$E[Y|A,B] = 0.1A+0.1B+0.1AB$$

What is $E[Y|A]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) here. That means we will average $E[Y|A,B]$ over all possible values of $B$. The result is:

$$\begin{align}
E[Y|A]&=0.1\cdot E[A|A]+0.1\cdot E[B|A]+0.1\cdot E[AB|A]\\
&=0.1\cdot A+0.1\cdot E[B|A]+0.1\cdot A\cdot E[B|A]\\
&=0.1\cdot (A+E[B|A]+A\cdot E[B|A])
\end{align}$$

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have $E[B|A]=E[B]$ and we can further simplify this:

$$E[Y|A]=0.1\cdot(A+0.5+0.5\cdot A)=0.05+0.15A$$